# Batch file renaming – inserting text from a list (in Python or Java)

Tags: java, python, file-rename

I'm finishing a business card production flow (excel > xml > indesign > single page pdfs) and I would like to insert the employees' names in the filenames.

What I have now:

```
BusinessCard_01_Blue.pdf
BusinessCard_02_Blue.pdf
BusinessCard_03_Blue.pdf (they are gonna go up to the hundreds)
```

What I need (I can manipulate the name list with regex easily):

```
BusinessCard_01_CarlosJorgeSantos_Blue.pdf
BusinessCard_02_TaniaMartins_Blue.pdf
BusinessCard_03_MarciaLima_Blue.pdf
```

I'm a Java and Python toddler. I've read the related questions, tried this in Automator (Mac) and Name Mangler, but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance, 
Gus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of names in the same order the files are produced, in Python it goes like this untested fragment:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

f = open('list.txt', 'r')
for n, name in enumerate(f):
    original_name = 'BusinessCard_%02d_Blue.pdf' % (n + 1)
    new_name = 'BusinessCard_%02d_%s_Blue.pdf' % (
                             n, ''.join(name.title().split()))
    if os.path.isfile(original_name):
        print "Renaming %s to %s" % (original_name, new_name),
        os.rename(original_name, new_name)
        print "OK!"
    else:
        print "File %s not found." % original_name
```

Comment: Hi Guys, amazing! Thanks for the inputs. It's gonna take me some time to understand these approaches, but I'm sure it will work.

I found that the program Paulo suggested was very didactic and easier for me.

Again, thanks a lot!
Best,
Gus

Answer (score 2):

Granted you have a map where to look at the right name you could do something like this in Java:

```
List<Files> originalFiles = ... 
for( File f : originalFiles ) { 
     f.renameTo( new File( getNameFor( f ) ) );
}
```

And define the `getNameFor` to something like:

```
public String getNameFor( File f ) { 
    Map<String,String> namesMap = ... 
    return namesMap.get( f.getName() );
}
```

In the map you'll have the associations:

```
BusinessCard_01_Blue.pdf => BusinessCard_01_CarlosJorgeSantos_Blue.pdf
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: BTW the `renameTo` method returns true if the value was changed, you might want to  keep track of that.

Answer (score 2):

In Python (tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, shutil, re

try: 
    pdfpath = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError: 
    pdfpath = os.curdir

employees = {1:'Bob', 2:'Joe', 3:'Sara'}    # emp_id:'name'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(pdfpath) if re.match("BusinessCard_[0-9]+_Blue.pdf", f)]
idnumbers = [int(re.search("[0-9]+", f).group(0)) for f in files]
filenamemap = zip(files, [employees[i] for i in idnumbers])
newfiles = [re.sub('Blue.pdf', e + '_Blue.pdf', f) for f, e in filenamemap]

for old, new in zip(files, newfiles):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(pdfpath, old), os.path.join(pdfpath, new))
```

EDIT: This now alters only those files that have not yet been altered.

Let me know if you want something that will build the the `employees` dictionary automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

Assuming you have implemented the naming logic already:

```
for f in os.listdir(<directory>):
    try:
        os.rename(f, new_name(f.name))
    except OSError:
        # fail
```

You will, of course, need to write a function `new_name` which takes the string `"BusinessCard_01_Blue.pdf"` and returns the string `"BusinessCard_01_CarlosJorgeSantos_Blue.pdf"`.